# How to update arguments of a role using host vars values in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, datadog

I am using Ansible [Datadog role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/Datadog/datadog) and trying to install and configure datadog agents in target servers however, i am stuck at a point where i need to use host variables and update a section of the playbook using these variables. The variable has got multiple values separated by a space. I want to ensure that these values are added in the playbook based on the variable values. Following example will help in understanding the requirement.

**Playbook:**

```
- hosts: servers
  roles:
    - { role: datadog.datadog, become: yes }
  vars:
    datadog_api_key: "{{ DD_API_KEY }}"
    datadog_config:
      tags:
        - "AID:"{{ AID }}"
```

Here, the tag value AID is using a host variable with the same name i.e., AID and in some cases this host variable can have values like the following:

`AID: 100 101 102 103`

Is there a way that the while executing tag section of the playbook is parsed based on the variable values in following format.

```
  tags:
    - AID: 100
    - AID: 101
    - AID: 102
    - AID: 103
```

I believe i cannot use templates for such requirements since the configurations are used under vars in the role. Any suggests would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the host variable `AID` a string or a list of string? In both cases - you need to split the value in `AID`to have a list of string - and then iterate over the list items and add that to the dict `datadog_config.tags` with tags: "{{ ['AID: '] | product(AID) | map('join') | list }}" - see https://www.itix.fr/blog/ansible-add-prefix-suffix-to-list/

Comment: AID values are updated as string values.

Comment: So you need to split the string parts in "AID: 100 101 .." into a list of [100,101,...] and then add the prefix (if you really need it). I would add it during execution) instead of the product()...

Answer (score 0):

As told by @TRW in the comments, using this should do the trick:

```
- hosts: servers
  roles:
    - { role: datadog.datadog, become: yes }
  vars:
    datadog_api_key: "{{ DD_API_KEY }}"
    datadog_config:
      tags: "{{ ['AID: ']|product(AID.split())|map('join')|list }}"
```